# zsh colours only work when command used in terminal directly

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to write a zsh script which can echo some useful information with colours. As a test I made the following file:

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo $fg[red] "test"
```

which should just output `test` in red, however when I run it it outputs `test` but it is in the default text colour rather then red.

If I just type `echo $fg[red] "test"` directly into my terminal, then it works correctly and I see the red `test`, but when I run my file with the above code, the colours don't work.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load `colors` first that is shipped with zsh (`/usr/share/zsh/functions/Misc/colors` for me) and initialized all the `$fg`, `$bg` and more variables

```sh
#!/bin/zsh
autoload colors && colors
echo $fg[red] "test"
```

will print a red `test`